# django models.DoesNotExist: matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, migrate

I am using Django 1.11 and typed below codes in models.py. It works fine when makemigrations, but it notices the error of "models.DoesNotExist" when do migrate.

The code in models.py:

```
class RecordType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='out',blank=True, verbose_name="name")


def get_record_type_default():
    return RecordType.objects.get_or_create(pk=1)[0].id


class PrimaryCategory(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(RecordType, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=get_record_type_default, verbose_name="type")


def get_primary_category_default():
    return PrimaryCategory.objects.get_or_create(pk=1)[0].id


class SecondaryCategory(models.Model):
    primary_category = models.ForeignKey(PrimaryCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=get_primary_category_default, verbose_name="1st category")


def get_secondary_category_default():
    return SecondaryCategory.objects.get_or_create(pk=1)[0].id


class Record(models.Model):
    secondary_category = models.ForeignKey(SecondaryCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=get_secondary_category_default, verbose_name="2nd category")
```

And here is the error message while doing migrate:

```
File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 464, in get_or_create
  return self.get(**lookup), False
File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 380, in get
  self.model._meta.object_name
datacore.models.DoesNotExist: SecondaryCategory matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Having default functions for foreign keys is problematic. The migration is done inside a database transaction, and the related model might also be in limbo. `get_or_create` will not quite work like it usually does. Might be possible to get this working by first creating a migration where the foreign key can be NULL, then another migration where you use make it non-nullable, and use that default function. You can also consider manually tweaking the migration script to change the order of the migration steps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think there should be some bugs in get_or_create function. I tried several times and find if I remove the secondary_category attribute from Record class first to do the migrate and then add it back and do migrate again, the codes will work.

Comment: I also suspect that the nested invoking depth of get_or_create is limited, because if I remove Record class, the codes will also work.

Answer (score -3):

you can use following way to create object:

```
get_object_or_404(RecordType, pk=id)
```

Comment: if you mean a database record by **"object"**, then it is definitely wrong. `get_object_or_404` does not create a record in database.

Comment: get_object_or_404 is used http responses, but has nothing to do with migrations.